# How to prioritize executing multipart in terraform?

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

I am writing terraform code that should run template_cloudinit_config
multipart sections , one part is suppose to create afile called :variables.json
which contains variables in json format , second part should run my python script
but looks like the python script is running before the json file is getting created
please see the below code:

```
        # Render a part using a `template_file`
data "template_file" "script" {
template = file("scripts/setup.py")
}

# Render a multi-part cloud-init config making use of the part
# above, and other source files
data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
gzip          = true
base64_encode = true

part {
content_type      = "text/x-shellscript"
filename = "run_src.sh"
content = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF1 > /tmp/variables.json
{
    "set_instance_type":"${var.set_instance_type}",
    "set_admin_username":"${var.set_admin_username}"
}
EOF1
EOF
}
# Main cloud-config configuration file.
part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = "${data.template_file.script.rendered}"
}
}
```

under resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" added :custom_data
custom_data = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered}"

my question is:
how can i run part 1 first to create the json file before running part 2 which
executing the python script that required the json file before executing

Comment: It's [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) running inside your VM that is responsible for interpreting this data rather than Terraform, and so I added a "cloud-init" label here in the hope that someone who is knowledgeable about cloud-init can help.

Comment: I think that what you want will probably require using [the cloud-config language](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html) to describe your intentions in more detail, instead of just using bare shell scripts.

Comment: @max - Are you able to solve this problem ?